# Failed to specialize function template <unknown-type std::invoke(_callable &&_Types&&> noexept(<expr>)

Tags: c++, multithreading

After commenting out all lines to do with **threads** the error went away.

> Failed to specialize function template: unknown-type std::invoke(_callable &&_Types&& noexept(expr)
>
> std::invoke: no matching overloaded function found

```
int main()
{
vector<Bunny*> bunny;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) bunny.push_back(new Bunny(random(20) + 20, 
random(3) + 1, random(2), 0));

thread updater(UpdateTotals, bunny);

for (;;)    
{
    
 //Nothing here yet

}

exiting = 1;
updater.join();
cin.get();
}

bool exiting = 0;
```

**UpdateTotals** function ( Takes vector parameter )
The thread will infinitely loop through this function until the main loop is exited.

```
void UpdateTotals(vector<Bunny*>& bun)
{

for (;;)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < bun.size(); i++)
    {
        if (bun[i]->isAlive() && !bun[i]->checked) {
            bun[i]->checked = 1;
            ++total::bunnies;

            switch (bun[i]->color)
            {
            case ref::white: ++total::color[ref::white];

                break;
            case ref::brown: ++total::color[ref::brown];

                break;
            case ref::black: ++total::color[ref::black];

            }

            if (bun[i]->gender == 'm') {
                ++total::gender[0];

            }
            else {
                ++total::gender[1];

            }

            if (bun[i]->mutant) {
                ++total::mutants;

            }


        }
        else if (!bun[i]->isAlive() && !bun[i]->checked)
        {
            if (bun[i]->gender == 'm') --total::gender[0];
            else --total::gender[1];

            if (bun[i]->mutant) --total::mutants;

            if (bun[i]->color == ref::black) --total::color[ref::black];
            else if (bun[i]->color == ref::brown) -- 
 total::color[ref::brown];
            else --total::color[ref::white];

            delete bun[i];
            bun.erase(bun.begin() + i);
            --total::bunnies;
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    }
    if (exiting) break;
}
```

Comment: What's `UpdateTotals`?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: Make it `thread updater(UpdateTotals, std::ref(bunny));`. That's needed to pass the parameter by reference; the default is passing by value.

Comment: Thank you it compiled like a charm. I think you should add your post down below so I can mark it as correct.